# Error when building iOS from Unity to Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

Getting the following error after Build and Run from Unity to Xcode. Any help appreciated.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _inflate_stream in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
     (maybe you meant: _unity_z_inflate_copyright, _unity_z_inflateCopy , _unity_z_inflateSyncPoint , _unity_z_inflateSync , _unity_z_inflateGetHeader , _unity_z_inflate_table , _unity_z_inflate_fast , _unity_z_inflatePrime , _unity_z_inflateSetDictionary , _il2cpp_class_is_inflated , _il2cpp_method_is_inflated , _unity_z_inflateEnd , _unity_z_inflateInit_ , _unity_z_inflateReset , _unity_z_inflate , _unity_z_inflateInit2_ , __Z27scripting_class_is_inflated17ScriptingClassPtr )
  "_zlibVersion", referenced from:
      _Curl_unencode_gzip_write in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
     (maybe you meant: _unity_z_zlibVersion)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      _inflate_stream in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
      _Curl_unencode_gzip_write in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
     (maybe you meant: _unity_z_inflateInit2_)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _inflate_stream in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
      _Curl_unencode_gzip_write in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
      _Curl_unencode_cleanup in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
     (maybe you meant: _unity_z_inflateEnd)
  "_inflateInit_", referenced from:
      _Curl_unencode_deflate_write in libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o)
     (maybe you meant: _unity_z_inflateInit_)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```